# How do I write this objective-c code snippet into Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, audiotoolbox

This is a couple lines of code taken pretty much verbatim from the GBA4iOS controller view that changes the length of a vibration:

```
void AudioServicesStopSystemSound(int);
void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(int, id, NSDictionary *);

@implementation vibeObject;

- (void)vibrate
{
    AudioServicesStopSystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    int64_t vibrationLength = 30;

    NSArray *pattern = @[@NO, @0, @YES, @(vibrationLength)];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dictionary[@"VibePattern"] = pattern;
    dictionary[@"Intensity"] = @1;

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, nil, dictionary);
}

@end
```

My attempt here just refuses to work under all circumstances:

```
func AudioServicesStopSystemSound(Int);
func AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(Int , NilLiteralConvertible, NSDictionary)();

func vibrate(){

    AudioServicesStopSystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    let vibrationLength = 30;

    let pattern: NSArray = [false, 0, true, vibrationLength];

    var dictionary:NSMutableDictionary;
    dictionary["VibePattern"] = pattern;
    dictionary["Intensity"] = 1;

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, nil, dictionary);
}
```

When left uncommented, it crashes SourceKit, but only in view controller. When I put it in its own file:

```
vibeObject.vibrate(<# RIGHT HERE IT TELLS ME "EXPECTED ',' SEPARATOR vibeObject#>);
```

I've tried everything I could, if you could help it'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the set of parenthesis after your "AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration" declaration.

From:

```
func AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(Int , NilLiteralConvertible, NSDictionary)();
```

To:

```
func AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(Int , NilLiteralConvertible, NSDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need the function declarations.  (In fact I'm not sure that works at all.)

This line:

```
 var dictionary:NSMutableDictionary;
```

Does not create a mutable dictionary, you need to write:

```
var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
```